# Apache Ivy exclude tag for dependencies

Tags: xml, ivy

I would like to exclude some jars in Apache Ivy resolve when i am downloading dependencies from selenium like selenium-safari-driver-2.53.1.jar ,selenium-edge-driver.2.53.1.jar ,selenium-support.jar and so on. However, after repeated attempts and trying out different combinations of matcher and type and it doesnt seem to work.Below is my Ivy.xml

```
<configurations>
        <conf name="core" description="only ivy jar, without any dependencies"/>
        <conf name="standalone" extends="core" description="to launch in standalone mode (from command line)"/>
        <conf name="default" extends="core" description="full ivy with all dependencies"/>
        <conf name="test" description="dependencies used for junit testing ivy" visibility="private"/>
        <conf name="source" description="ivy sources"/>
    </configurations>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="ivy" type="jar" conf="core"/>
        <artifact name="ivy" type="source" ext="jar" conf="source"/>
    </publications>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-java" rev="2.53.1"/>
        <dependency org="org.testng" name="testng" rev="6.8"/>
        <exclude type="javadoc" ext="*" conf="*"/>
        <exclude type="source" ext="*" conf="*"/>
        <exclude type="license" ext="*" conf="*"/>
        <exclude org="seleniumhq.selenium" module="safari-driver" matcher="regexp" />

    </dependencies>
```

Kindly let me know how to include these exclusions effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Ivy will resolve all the dependencies. Exclusions can be used to determine the contents of a particular ivy configuration.

You need to include configuration mappings, in general you just use the "default" configuration of the remote module, which will exclude source and javadocs:

```
<dependency org="??" name="??" rev="???" conf="mylocalconf->default">
```

## Example

```
├── build.xml
├── ivy.xml
└── target
    └── lib
        ├── cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar
        ├── commons-codec-1.10.jar
        ├── commons-exec-1.3.jar
        ├── commons-io-2.4.jar
        ├── commons-logging-1.2.jar
        ├── gson-2.3.1.jar
        ├── guava-19.0.jar
        ├── htmlunit-driver-2.21.jar
        ├── httpclient-4.5.1.jar
        ├── httpcore-4.4.3.jar
        ├── jna-4.1.0.jar
        ├── jna-platform-4.1.0.jar
        ├── netty-3.5.7.Final.jar
        ├── selenium-api-2.53.1.jar
        ├── selenium-java-2.53.1.jar
        ├── selenium-leg-rc-2.53.1.jar
        └── selenium-support-2.53.1.jar
```

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="compile" description="Required to compile application"/>
        <conf name="runtime" description="Additional run-time dependencies" extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="test"    description="Required for test only" extends="runtime"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- compile dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-java" rev="2.53.1" conf="compile->default">
          <exclude org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-chrome-driver"/>
          <exclude org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-edge-driver"/>
          <exclude org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-firefox-driver"/>
          <exclude org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-ie-driver"/>
          <exclude org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-remote-driver"/>
          <exclude org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-safari-driver"/>
        </dependency>

        <!-- test dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.testng" name="testng" rev="6.8" conf="test->default"/>
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

Notes:

- Configurations "runtime" and "test" are supersets of "compile"
- Each dependency has a configuration mapping
- Excludes are local to a single dependency

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="resolve">
        <ivy:resolve/>
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="target/lib/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" conf="compile"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- The "target/lib" directory is only populated with the dependencies that are in the "compile" configuration.